# any help for Code coverage for a try-catch block

Tags: trigger, code-coverage

**Trigger**

```
trigger GE_PW_GenerateProfSumFAs on GE_PW_Profsum__c (after insert, after update) {

    Triggers_Switch__c tsObj = Triggers_Switch__c.getValues('GE_PW_GenerateProfSumFAs');
    if(tsObj != null && tsObj.GE_HQ_Execute__c == true){  


    List<GE_PW_Profsum_FA__c> profsumFAs = new List<GE_PW_Profsum_FA__c>();
    List<GE_PW_Profsum__c> matchingProfsums = new List<GE_PW_Profsum__c>();

    GE_PW_ProfsumHandler handler = new GE_PW_ProfsumHandler();
    for (GE_PW_Profsum__c record : Trigger.new) {
         system.debug('flag value is ::'+record.GE_PW_Profsum_F_A_Items__c);
        boolean hasNewItems = !String.isBlank(record.GE_PW_Profsum_F_A_Items__c)
            && (Trigger.isInsert || !Trigger.oldMap.containsKey(record.Id) || Trigger.oldMap.get(record.Id).GE_PW_Profsum_F_A_Items__c != record.GE_PW_Profsum_F_A_Items__c) && record.Energy_PSource__c == 'File';
        if (hasNewItems) {
            try {
                system.debug('inside loop');
                profsumFAs.addAll(handler.ExtractFAItems(record));
                matchingProfsums.add(record);
            } catch (GE_PW_ProfsumHandler.InvalidOperationException ex) {
                record.GE_PW_Profsum_F_A_Items__c.addError(ex);
            }
        }
    }
    if (profsumFAs.size() > 0) {
        insert profsumFAs;
    }
    if (matchingProfsums.size() > 0) {
        handler.ClearFAItemsData(matchingProfsums);
    }
  }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest(seeAlldata=true)
public class GE_PW_ProfsumHandler_Test
 {
 static testMethod void lastModifiedServerTest2(){
  GE_PW_Profsum__c profsum=new GE_PW_Profsum__c(GE_PW_Renewables_PSource__c = 'File');
     //profsum.GE_PW_Profsum_F_A_Items__c = 'test';
     insert profsum;
     GE_PW_Profsum_FA__c ge= new GE_PW_Profsum_FA__c(Profsum__c=profsum.id, Name='test');
     insert ge;
     //profsum.GE_PW_Profsum_F_A_Items__c = ge.name;
     //update profsum;

 }

  //GE_PW_ProfSumHandler ProfTest = new GE_PW_ProfSumHandler();
static testMethod void InsertingTest()
 {
     GE_PW_ProfSumHandler ProfTest = new GE_PW_ProfSumHandler();
     ProfTest.insertTest();
  } 

}
```

Comment: Hi Neha, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask]. Have you made any attempt at all to solve this problem on your own? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please **[edit]** your post with any additional information.

Comment: The only code that really matters here is the `GE_PW_ProfsumHandler.ExtractFAItems` method.

Comment: Suggest you had over to trailhead are review the Apex Test module. Your test method is not a test method at all and is using some very bad practices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you already have test methods that insert/update data that exercises the "happy" path and causes `handler.ExtractFAItems` to run so that values are inserted.

To test the path where the `GE_PW_ProfsumHandler.InvalidOperationException` is thrown, the ideal is to create additional test methods that insert/update data that cause the exception to be thrown. This is the best approach as it reflects the real-use situation.

Occasionally you may have to resort to using an `@TestVisible` flag in the code that throws the exception (that your test methods set) to make it artificially throw the exception if you can't find a way to generate the exception using data but want to test the error handling.

Comment: @NehaAgarwal I can't provide much of an example that would help. You need to examine the `ExtractFAItems` method and figure out under what conditions the exception is thrown and generate that condition in your extra test methods.

Comment: thank you
&& (Trigger.isInsert || !Trigger.oldMap.containsKey(record.Id) || Trigger.oldMap.get(record.Id).GE_PW_Profsum_F_A_Items__c != record.GE_PW_Profsum_F_A_Items__c) && record.Energy_PSource__c == 'File';         
any help in this line for coverage